# Extracting polygons coordinates in counter-clockwise direction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, vertices, extract

I am working with a polygon data set and as per the requirement I need to extract polygon vertices/coordinates in counter-clockwise direction/fashion.

Is there any tool or software available for extracting the same?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The Esri default for geometry is *left-hand rule*. This should apply to all data sources, including shapefiles (which natively use *right-hand rule*). There is no provision for counterclockwise because interior rings are always stored in the reverse of exterior.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will extract out the coordinates into a list then reverse the list. It takes advantage of a [parameter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm#S2_GUID-3CB1DFF4-983D-445F-9CB2-0FF1CD4B4880) for the cursor which is to explode the geometry (in this case a polygon) into its vertices.

```py
import arcpy

aPolygonLayer = r"C:\GIS_DATA\fGDB_RiverBasin9.gdb\test"

aList = list()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(aPolygonLayer,"SHAPE@XY","","",True) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        aList.append(row[0])

# Before
print("Before")
print(aList)

# After
print("After")
aList.reverse()
print(aList)
```